# How to unit test multiple AWS Lambda functions in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytest, aws-cdk

I want to use CDK's built-in assertions to test multiple lambda functions in my stack. So far I was able to test only one lambda function.

```
def test_lambda_function():
app = core.App()
stack = RadBackendStack(app, "rad-backend")
template = assertions.Template.from_stack(stack)
print(template)
template.has_resource_properties("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
    "Architectures": ["arm64"],
    "Runtime": "python3.8",
    "Timeout": 1
})
```

This is the lambda testing function I wrote. And I expect it to test all the lambda functions in my stack.

```
self._lambda = _lambda.Function(
        self,
        "test_function",
        code=_lambda.AssetCode.from_asset('src'),
        handler="lambda.handler",
        architecture=_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        timeout=Duration.seconds(1)
    )
self._lambda_2 = _lambda.Function(
        self,
        "test_function_2",
        code=_lambda.AssetCode.from_asset('src'),
        handler="lambda.handler",
        architecture=_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_2_7,
        timeout=Duration.seconds(2)
    )
```

These are the lambda functions. I expect the second to fail but pytest is only testing the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_resource_properties` tests whether a resource exists with those properties. It succeeds because there is a lambda with those properties. This is documented in [the typescript implementation comments](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/74318c7d22bfc00de9e005f68a0a6aaa58c7db39/packages/%40aws-cdk/assertions/lib/template.ts#L74).

If both lambdas have the same properties you want to test, you can use [`template.resource_properties_count_is`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.assertions/README.html?highlight=hasresourceproperties#counting-resources) and assert the count is 2:

```
template.resource_properties_count_is("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
    "Architectures": ["arm64"],
    "Runtime": "python3.8",
    "Timeout": 1
}, 2);
```

Comment: For those curious of the docs in JS, here's the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html